# Метод наследника абстрактного класса для экземпляра абстрактного класса

Tags: java

Есть абстрактный класс `Soldier` и его наследник `Swordsman` . У `Swordsman` есть метод `attack`, который не был объявлен в родительском классе. В `main` я создаю экземпляр  `Soldier swordsman = new Swordsman()`  и хочу использовать метод `attack` класса `Swordsman`, но, поскольку в `Soldier` его нет, не могу использовать. Возможно ли как-то сделать метод юзабельным, не объявляя его в родительском классе?

Comment: Что не получается?

Comment: вызвать несуществующий метод невозможно. либо кастуйте так, как вам показали в ответе, либо не приводите все к родителю (что логично): Swordsman swordsman = new Swordsman()